# VS Code attach to container in k8s fails with mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www': Permission denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes, visual-studio-code

Running VS code on Ubuntu 20.10

Based on this guide:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container#_attach-to-a-container-in-a-kubernetes-cluster

I am trying to attach to a running container in a k8s cluster and edit a file in that container using vs code:

[image]

As a result another vs code instance opens but prints this error:

```
[2260 ms] 
[2261 ms] mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www': Permission denied
[2261 ms] Exit code 1
[2274 ms] Command in container failed: mkdir -p /var/www/.vscode-server/bin/054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335_1621844063707
```

Looks like its trying to create that directory in the remote container but is that necessary to connect and open/edit a file on the remote container in vs code?

Or is it somehow possible to specify a path for where to store this content inside the container with adequate permissions?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your option **Attach Visual Studio Code** does not originate from the official Kubernetes extension from VS Code.

You can visit this open issue on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/Azure/vscode-kubernetes-tools/issues/739) to learn more about it.

Comment: Not sure if its relevant but I am running VS code on Ubuntu/linux and from what I can read that issue is related to wsl on windows? I have updated the question.

Comment: If you have the updated version, that's good to go. Are there any other similar plugins installed, like the GitHub issue talked of? By the way, what you can try doing is for testing purposes, you can execute can a preStart command on startup or mention in your Dockerfile to give permissions to that specific directly (only for testing purpose). By using this, you'll be able to debug what's the problem. It seems that VS Code does try to write some of it's configs.

Comment: Yes as can been seen from the output in my question its trying to write to: mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www': Permission denied probably because that the working dir location when attaching to the running container. Unless that can somehow be configured/change in vs code when attaching there is probably no way to get this working :-(

Comment: @u123 Why don't you try creating that directory in advance and give it open permissions?